# Why is my Springboot deployment to EBS not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a small SpringBoot application to EBS. I think I have done everything right, including setting up an RDS database, but the deployment fails and I get an error with health degraded as : Following services are not running: application-web-1.

My variables are setup as follows

```
GRADLE_HOME

/usr/local/gradle


JAVA_HOME

/usr/lib/jvm/java


M2

/usr/local/apache-maven/bin


M2_HOME

/usr/local/apache-maven


SERVER_PORT

5000


SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD

***


SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL

jdbc:mysql://***.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/ebdb


SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME

***


SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM

org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect


SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO

***


SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE

prod
```

Any advice on how to debug?

My logs below:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2019/03/17 19:02:16 [error] 4817#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.29.139.73, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 19:02:17 [error] 4817#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.29.139.73, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 19:02:25 [error] 4817#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.29.139.73, server: , request: "GET /links/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/links/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 19:02:26 [error] 4817#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 82.29.139.73, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/links/"
2019/03/17 19:57:28 [error] 4817#0: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 178.73.215.171, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
2019/03/17 20:53:11 [error] 4817#0: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 104.152.52.21, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
2019/03/17 20:57:57 [error] 4817#0: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 20:57:58 [error] 4817#0: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 21:06:08 [error] 29457#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 21:06:08 [error] 29457#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 21:15:47 [error] 30143#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 21:15:48 [error] 30143#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 21:15:54 [error] 30143#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 21:15:54 [error] 30143#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 21:25:28 [error] 30981#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 21:25:28 [error] 30981#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 21:29:36 [error] 31520#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 21:29:36 [error] 31520#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2019/03/17 21:34:37 [error] 31520#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2019/03/17 21:34:37 [error] 31520#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 151.229.68.196, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico", host: "ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ddemo-env.ipmbyempmi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

Comment: Do you have logs from the Java application?  It looks like it didn't start.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'm not sure if this will work for you, but this is how I solved the

> Following services are not running: application-web-1.

issue. I ssh'd onto my elastic beanstalk instance and cd'd to the /var/log directory. I noticed that there was a

> web-1.error.log

log showing. I vi'd that log file and there was the exception that was causing the deployment to fail. A txt file that was nested inside a folder within my resources folder was not visible and the following exception was being thrown.

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/vegetables/vegetables.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/vegetables/vegetables.txt

This occurred because I was using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver to get the resources, then traversing the resources by filename, and directly trying to access the file by using resource.getFile(). Instead of getting the data by the file. I used

> byte[] dataArr = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(resource.getInputStream());

and that allowed me to use the data in the byte array the same way I used it by accessing the file directly. I hope this helps.